# how to auto add two decimal places to the input field in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to auto add two decimal places to input number when user is entering the number and also i want to add thousand separators as well in angular 6.[image]

Comment: have you tried making a directive for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you basically need is masking your input. angular2-text-mask provides you a directive which you can use on your input elements like this:

```
<input [textMask]="{mask: amountMask}">
```

Where amountMask is a property declared your component:

```
 public amountMask= createNumberMask({
        prefix: '',
        allowDecimal: true,
        decimalLimit: 2
    });
```

To install angular2-text-mask package:

```
npm i angular2-text-mask --save
```

---

**createNumberMask** is part of the text-mask-addons package, to install:

```
npm i text-mask-addons --save
```

Then you need to import like this:

```
import {createNumberMask} from 'text-mask-addons';
```

---

Github page for further info on angular2-text-mask

https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2

Github page for text-mask-addons

https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons/

Demo:
https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/

Answer (score 0):

there is in build pipe for converting the number to decimal use the pipe with your ngModel like

```
[(ngModel)]="yourvalue | number:'1.2-2'"
```

in ts file

```
yourvalue : number ;
```

Comment: no it is  working it give a error when i used the pipe inside the ngModel

Comment: You can't use a pipe with 2 way binding afaik. Try to split up ngModel into [ngModel]="yourvalue" and (ngModelChange)="changeYourvalue($event)", beware: in "changeYourvalue" method you'll have to convert the variable back.

Comment: thank you but it not working. I just want to display the input with decimal for an example if user input 20000 it should show 20,000.00 in the front end.