# Restrict Character and Number after decimal upto 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a requirement where the user should allow the only number with 2 decimal places

1. User should also not allow entering any Character or Special Character
2. User should also not allow entering a number after 2 decimal places

Example: User tries to enter a number after `7979.78`

I have tried with this Regex but its not working :

```js
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {
        if (text) {
          var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9\.]([0-9]{1,2})?$/g, '');

          if (transformedInput !== text) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return transformedInput;
        }
        return undefined;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: We used this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982631/how-to-auto-add-two-decimal-places-to-the-input-field-in-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach with the regex `\d+\.*\d{0,2}`

```js
console.log("21.123".match(/\d+\.*\d{0,2}/)[0]) // 21.12
console.log("21".match(/\d+\.*\d{0,2}/)[0]) // 21
```